# Is it necessary to call setDoubleBuffered on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

The Java tutorial says that double buffering is enabled by default in many components.

> Swing uses this technique in many of its components, usually enabled by default, using the setDoubleBuffered method.

The `isDoubleBuffered` returns true for a `JPanel`.
Is it then redundant to call `setDoubleBuffered(true)` in a game whose board is a `JPanel`? (Needed for reducing flickering and having smoother animation.)

This may be a logical conclusion, but in my experience, `isFocusable` returns true, but we need to call `setFocusable` despite to be able to handle key events.

**Edit**

I have added some code snippets.

```
private void initBoard() {
    ...
    setDoubleBuffered(true); // Is it necessary?

    // isFocusable returns true, but when setFocusable is not called
    // key events are not processed
    setFocusable(true); 

    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

    exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        doGameCycle();       
    }, INITIAL_DELAY, PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   ...
}

private void doGameCycle() {

    updateBalloons();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (isRunning) {
        doDrawing(g);
    } else {
        gameOver(g);
    }

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}  

private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        ...
        System.out.println("key pressed");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if the documentation is correct? I almost suspect your focus example is bumping your jpanel in the focus cycle, and not just enabling focus.

Comment: No, I am double checking. The Java tutorial has some well known mistakes, for instance JDBC examples do not handle releasing of resources correctly.

Comment: Do you want some method to confirm double buffering is happening? Usually I would just make the animations and tune them afterwards. I have never found double buffering to be an issue, but when drawing gets to heavy I use my own BufferedImage for drawing off of the EDT.

Comment: I am OK with the confirmation that it is redundant to call the method. But I would look/test the code that would confirm double buffering is happending out of curiosity.

Comment: Calling doGameCycle out of the context of Event Dispatching Thread is an issue. This could be setting up condition for dirty reads. As a general recommendation, you should using a Swing Timer instead. I would also recommend using the key bindings api over KeyListener

Comment: There is a difference in functionality between isFocudable and hasFocus. The first determines if the component CAN gain focus, the other determines IF the component currently HAS focus. Unlike doubleBuffer, which is either on or off

Comment: I've not had a need to use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync()` either

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did not realize that `ScheduledExecutorService` goes out of EDT. I saw it somewhere recommended for creating optimal frame rates. (I think it is java.util.Timer that is then preferred to Swing timer. )
I am going to try the key bindings and see how it behaves with the focus.

The `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync()` is needed for smooth animations on Linux. I can confirm it.

Comment: @JanBodnar `ScheduledExecutorService` is probably using a `Thread` or even if its using a `java.util.Timer`, it's still a bad idea

Comment: I tend to disagree, I often do my main loop off of the EDT, and then repaint because I do a lot of work in my main loop. Some effort needs to be made to keep the state consistent, but I usually prefer drawing something outdated versus a slow/sluggish ui. That being said, doubleBuffered seems to be outdated a bit since there are newer methods such as BufferedStrategy. Also, I cannot see a difference with/without it (or the Toolkit/sync).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isDoubleBuffered` is enabled by default in `JPanel`. You don't need to call it second time. If your painting code is written correctly and invoked using proper events, then all should be fine. Usually you need to override `paintComponent` and handle all the drawings there for java swing classes. Then to request refreshing you need to call `repaint()`. That's all. To be able to help you more I need to see your painting code, so please include it in this question if you need additional help. I don't know about any issues with isFocusable and setFocusable, can you provide any example of code showing such bahaviour?

Comment: I have added some code snippets. Animation should be OK, I was confused by the focus inconsistence.